# In Laravel, mocking an eloquent query on a model

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, mocking, mockery

I'm stuck on Laravel 4.2 for now (with phpunit and mockery) but the same should apply to later versions.

I have a Repository for my `FxRate` model. It has a method to get an FX rate vs GBP which contains this eloquent call:

```
$query = \FxRate::where('currency', $currency )
    ->where('fx_date', $fxDate->format('Y-m-d') )
    ->first();

return $query->rate_to_gbp;
```

In my unit test I'd like to mock this call so I can define the query result that would be returned by this call rather than relying on the database to have a value within it.

My attempt goes something like this:

```
$mocked_query_result = (object) ['rate_to_gbp' => 1.5];

FxRate::shouldReceive('where')
       ->once()
       ->andReturn($mocked_query_result);
```

But I'm fairly sure this won't work as the initial static call to `FxRate` should return some query object that accepts a further `where()` call and a `first()`.

Is there a clean way of mocking this?

Answer (score 3):

You should pass an instance of your model into the repository in the constructor:

```
public function __construct(FXRate $model) 
{
    $this->model = $model;
}
```

Then your query becomes:

```
$query = $this->model->where('currency', $currency)...etc
```

Then you pass a mocked model to the repo when you instantiate it:

```
$mockModel = Mockery::mock('FXRate');
// This could be better, and you should use correct with() calls but hey, it's only an example
$mockModel->shouldReceive('where')
    ->twice()
    ->andReturn($mockModel);
$mockModel->shouldReceive('first')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn($mocked_query_result);
$repo = new Repo($mockModel)
$this->assertEquals($mocked_query_result, $repo->testableMethod());
```

Further edit following comments. You can return a mock of any model but I find mocking the real model helps with readability:

```
$mockFXRate = Mockery::mock('FXRate');
$mockFXRate->shouldReceive('where')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn($mockFXRate);
$mockFXRate->shouldReceive('first')
    ->once()
    ->andReturn($mocked_query_result);
FXRate::shouldReceive('where')
    ->andReturn($mockFXRate);
```

Comment: [The docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/testing#mocking-facades) say it's possible to mock the facade; that's not the problem - and I'm happy using the facade in this case. The difficulty is the chained methods which looks as if I'd need to return a new mock object for each method in the chain.

Comment: @harryg - got you. I take the approach in the edit. Maybe not the best so someone might suggest something else. There is a Mockery::self() object to return but I had problems getting that to work and never persevered with it, so could be worth looking at.

Comment: Hmm I'm still not sure that works as `FxRate::where(...)` doesn't return an instance of `FxRate`; it returns an `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` instance which accepts the further chained mothods. `first()` then returns the result.

Comment: @harryg - IME, andReturn() can return anything you want as long as what it returns provides the chained methods. I would use FXRate as the mock here for readability and continuity. Not sure if I've done this from a Facade like you're wanting to, but this approach of a mock returning the same mock and having multiple shouldReceive() works for me. Pending a more elegant solution.

Comment: If you do not care about the arguments passed to the `where` calls you can use `$mockFXRate->shouldReceive('where->where->first')->andReturn($mocked_query_result);`. http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/demeter_chains.html

Comment: @Petter - I saw that the other day, and it's definitely relevant here, so good call!